# Error while using Subcaption package

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, subfloats, subcaption

I am trying to use the `subcaption` package in my code but it throws errors. Here is the preamble of my code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}



%%% Maths and science packages

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        calc,
        patterns,
        positioning
    }
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.16,
        samples=200,
        clip=false,
        my axis style/.style={
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            legend pos=outer north east,
            x axis line style={
                ->,
            },
            y axis line style={
                <->,
            },
            legend style={
                font=\footnotesize
            },
            label style={
                font=\footnotesize
            },
            tick label style={
                font=\footnotesize
            },
            xlabel style={
                at={
                    (ticklabel* cs:1)
                },
                anchor=west,
                font=\footnotesize,
            },
            ylabel style={
                at={
                    (ticklabel* cs:1)
                },
                anchor=west,
                font=\footnotesize,
            },
            xlabel=$X$,
            ylabel=$Y$
        },
    }
    \tikzset{
        >=stealth
    }

%%% Tables and figures packages

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
    \captionsetup{
        format=plain,
        labelfont=bf,
        font=small,
        justification=centering
    }
    
%%% Numbers and sets

\newcommand{\E}{\mathrm{e}}

\title{Monthly report May 2022}
\author{kashwin975 }
\date{May 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
```

Comment: Please add the error message and make your example minimal.

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Please complete your document example! If I add into document body `\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-duck}
        \caption{Image A}
        \label{fig:A}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Image B}
    \label{fig:B}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{Planta Piloto SICAPI}
    \label{fig.sicapi}
\end{figure}
` and terminate it with `\end{document}, compilation works fine.

Comment: Please provide a full minimal example (= no comments, irrelevant packages, etc.) You probably don't need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` at all, but you certainly don't need it twice.